# Is it possible to call a web form in multiple master pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, webforms, master-pages

I have a web form and I want it to be accessible for masterpage1 and masterpage2. Is it possible? If yes, how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A page cannot have multiple masterpages

Comment: A page can have multiple nested masterpages at the same time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For simplification let's say you have stored a status within a `Session` which chooses the master page codebehind. In this example you can have 2 master pages and use only one of them at the same time:

```
//PreInit event of your desired page
protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Page.MasterPageFile))
    {
        if (Session["MyStatus"] == "1")
        {
            Page.MasterPageFile = "~/MyMaster1.master";
        }
        else
        {
            Page.MasterPageFile = "~/MyMaster2.master";
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to nest two masterpages dynamically you can do it this way. Here you have 2 master pages simultaniously:

```
protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Page.MasterPageFile))
    {
        if (Session["NestMaster"] == "1")
        {
            //setting a MasterPage to the Masterpage of the current page
            Page.Master.MasterPageFile = "~/MasterMaster.master";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @fubo. :) It really helped me a lot. :)